# Lexicographic sort on object of type char** is causing issues sometimes

Tags: c

Let's say I have `n` strings stored inside that object of type `char** lista` and each can have different size. So for example `strlen(lista[0]) = 10` but `strlen(lista[7]) = 14`.

And because the sizes can be different, I made the `temp` variable always have the appriopriate size. But maybe I did it wrong? Because for a very long list with long elements, my code never seems to end. For small lista it works fine. Or maybe there is another way to do this better?

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
      if(strcmp(lista[i], lista[j]) > 0) {
         char* temp;
         if(strlen(lista[i]) > strlen(lista[j])) {
            temp = (char*)calloc(strlen(lista[i])+1, sizeof(char));
            lista[j] = (char*)realloc(lista[j](strlen(lista[i])+strlen(lista[j])+1)*sizeof(char));
         }
         else {
            temp = (char*)calloc(strlen(lista[j])+1, sizeof(char));
            lista[i] = (char*)realloc(lista[i], (strlen(lista[i])+strlen(lista[j])+1)*sizeof(char));
         }
         if(!temp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to calloc() for temp!\n)");
         }
         if(!lista[i] || !lista[j]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to realloc()!\n");
            return -1;
         }
         strcpy(temp, lista[i]);
         strcpy(lista[i], lista[j]);
         strcpy(lista[j], temp);

         free(temp);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: And instead of copying the strings like you're doing, **just swap the pointers**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle How can I do this when my string is stored in lista[0] and another is stored in lista[1] , because applying pointer-swap on this I'm not sure. char* temp = *lista[0];  *lista[0] = *lista[1];  *lista[1] = temp; I think I write it wrong like that but I don't know how to write it correct :/

Comment: That looks wrong to me, too.  But `char *temp = lista[0]; lista[0] = lista[1]; lista[1] = temp` looks okay.

Comment: Use `qsort`, do not write your own sorting function.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
    if (strcmp(lista[i], lista[j]) > 0) {
        char *temp;
        temp = lista[i];
        lista[i] = lista[j];
        lista[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

It is often a good idea to treat `casts` as if they were very precious and you only have a few to give away.  Casts subvert the type system, and make code difficult to understand.